# Finding 'closest' function subject to constraints on derivatives

Tags: derivatives, optimization, discrete-optimization

Suppose I have a real-valued function $f(t)$ for $t\in[0,T]$ s.t. $f'''(t)$ is defined as piecewise constant values:

$$
f'''(t) = 
\begin{cases}
k_0, & 0 < t \le t_0 \\
k_1, &  t_0 < t \le t_1 \\
\cdots \\
k_n, & t_{n-1} < t \le t_n
\end{cases}
$$

subject to the following end-point constraints:

$$f(0)=0 \quad f(T)=X_T \quad f'(0) = 0 \quad f'(T) = V_T \quad f''(0) = 0 \quad f''(T) = 0$$

I want to find a new function $g(t)$ subject to the following constraints $\forall t \in [0,T]$:

$$g'(t) \le V_{max} \quad g''(t) \le A_{max} \quad g'''(t) \le J_{max}$$

Where $g(t)$ has the same end-point constraints as $f(t)$, with the assumption that $V_T \le V_{max}$.

I want to choose this function in such a way that $g(t)$ is as 'close' as possible to $f(t)$ over the interval, but I have flexibility in how to define this 'closeness' criterion.  I'm looking for suggestions on a choice of criterion that will help make this problem easy to solve while still satisfying the spirit of the requirement.  For instance, I could choose to minimize $\int_{0}^T{(g(t)-f(t))^2dt}$, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that or whether it's a good choice of criterion.

Right now I have a solution for my application that addresses this algorithmically, by using a discrete sampling of $f(t)$ and 'smoothing' it repeatedly via convolution with discrete filters until a discrete estimate of the derivatives satisfies all of the constraints.  This sort-of works, but I'm like to know if there is a more rigorous way to approach this and find some optimal solution.

For those who are curious, the physical application here is a motion control system where I have an idealized motion path I'd like to follow, but need to impose constraints on the requested jerk, acceleration and velocity in order to prevent excessive torques in the motor.

---

UPDATE:

I think my definition of $f(t)$ means that it is composed piecewise of cubic polynomials. Is this right?

Suppose I model $g(t)$ in the same way?  I can divide up my pieces s.t. there is a single $\Delta t = t_i - t_{i-1} \quad \forall i \in [1,n]$.  I can choose this value at a resolution that will be useful for my purposes.  I can then define $g'''(t)$ in the same way as $f'''(t)$, with different constants; let's call those $q_i$.

Now that the two functions are broken into pieces with the same intervals, I should be able to simplify this a bit.  For ease of notation, let's define each piece like this:

$$ f_i'''(t) = k_i \quad g_i'''(t) = q_i $$

Now if I some have criterion function C I want to maximize, I think I can compute my overall value using:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^{\Delta t} C(f_i(t),g_i(t)) dt$$

I'm not sure where to proceed from here, though.  It seems like any analytical expansion for $f_i(t)$ and $g_i(t)$ is going to be pretty complicated, even before I choose the criterion.

On a side note, my apologies for any imprecision or use of incorrect terminology; my last math class was quite a while ago.